# CORS Preflight Request succeeded but the request fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-code-403, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a frontend which is sending a POST request to an endpoint using XMLHttpRequest. It has some data and xml file sent in form data. My backend has a spring cloud gateway which has CORS enabled.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "https://myFrontEndSite.com"
            allowedMethods: "*"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowCredentials: true
```

the weird problem one of my user is facing is that when sending a specific file in the post request, they get a CORS error in console and 403 error when checking the call in the network tab of inspector. i can't seem to see if it is a red herring. I am able to import the file which the user cannot to that endpoint. the user is able to import other files to that endpoint.

I have checked the network tab in the inspector. the preflight succeeds but the actual request fails with 403 error. i opened the request but it's response says nothing to preview

Comment: The CORS error is probably only a consequence of the 403 error. If the POST request is authenticated with a session cookie, this might be blocked as a third-party cookie if your frontend and backend have different top-level domains (`myfrontendsite.com` vs. `mybackendsite.com`). This would explain the behavior.

Comment: Yes the POST request is authenticated via a session cookie but I don’t think that cookie is being blocked because the same endpoint works when sending a different xml file